# SAPUI5 PlanningCalendar set startDate

Tags: sapui5

I'm not able to reset the PlanningCalendar back to the initial startDate.
So, after clicking on Today or the Navigate Back or Foreward arrows there is no way of getting back to the initial start date.
I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, but you can find a working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8dW4bxvNwH9rBQxT?preview)

Here is the controller

```js
sap.ui.define(
  [
    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel',
    'sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel',
    'sap/m/MessageToast'
  ],
  function (Controller, JSONModel, ResourceModel, MessageToast) {
    'use strict';
    var PageController = Controller.extend('view.Main', {
      onInit: function () {
        var oModel = new JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({...});
        var oView = this.getView();
        oView.setModel(oModel);
      },
      dateFormatter: function (sDate) {
        return new Date(sDate);
      },
      resetStartDate: function () {
        var oView = this.getView();
        var oPlanningCalendar = oView.byId('PC1');
        var startDate = oPlanningCalendar.getStartDate();
        oPlanningCalendar.setStartDate(startDate);
        MessageToast.show("'resetStartDate' event fired.");
      },
      handleStartDateChange: function (oEvent) {
        var oView = this.getView();
        var oPlanningCalendar = oView.byId('PC1');
        var startDate = oPlanningCalendar.getStartDate();
        MessageToast.show("'startDateChange' event fired.\n\nNew start date is " + startDate.toString());
      }
    });
    return PageController;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the following two lines of code.

```
 var startDate = oPlanningCalendar.getStartDate();
 oPlanningCalendar.setStartDate(startDate);
```

You get the date from current Planning Calendar, and then set the date back to it.
That means you do nothing.

Maybe you need to get the start date on initial of Planning Calendar. Not at the time you want to do the reset.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that getStartDate() returns the start or initial date of the Planning Calendar, but it seems it is returning the start date of the curent view